# Passing objects and variables using `require` in `Node.js`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on moving routing methods from `app.js` to separate files.

I managed to do it using (in `app.js`):

```
var userRoutes = require('./serverRoutes/userRoutes');
app.use('/userRoutes', userRoutes);
app.post('/user/login', userRoutes);
```

I can see that routing is being done.

I have some variables in my `app.js` like:
- `tokens` array
- `jwtSecretKey`string
- `jwt` encryption module
- `User` which is mongoose schema

I would like to pass them and make them usable by routing methods inside `userRoutes.js` file.

I do not know how to do it.

Another question.

I also have some 'helper' type methods I would like to use in different 'routing' files.

I do not know how to pass them either.

This is how I deal with 'routing' files:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/user/login', function (request, response) {
    var email = request.body.email;
    var password = request.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: email, password: password },
        function (err, user) {
            if (err)
                response.send(err);

            if (user) {
                var expires = new Date();

                expires.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 5);

                var token = jwt.encode({
                    email: email,
                    expires: expires
                }, jwtTokenSecret);

                tokens.push(token);
                response.send(200, { access_token: token });
            } else {
                response.send(401, { message: "User not found" });

            }
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: *"Another question."* Ask **one** question/question, and make the question you ask clear. This question is not clear, not least because: What does `resolve` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what the "resolve" part of your title has to do with your question, but I can answer the rest of what you discuss in your question.

> I have some variables in my app.js... I would like to pass them and
>   make them usable by routing methods inside userRoutes.js file.

The usual way to share some settings with another module is to pass them to that module in a module constructor or a module method:

```
var userRoutes = require('./serverRoutes/userRoutes')({
    tokens: tokens, 
    jwtSecretKey: jwtSecretKey, 
    jwt: jwt, 
    User: User
});
```

Then, inside that userRoutes module:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwtSecretKey, jwt, User, tokens;

router.post('/user/login', function (request, response) {
    var email = request.body.email;
    var password = request.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: email, password: password },
        function (err, user) {
            if (err)
                response.send(err);

            if (user) {
                var expires = new Date();

                expires.setDate((new Date()).getDate() + 5);

                var token = jwt.encode({
                    email: email,
                    expires: expires
                }, jwtSecretKey);

                tokens.push(token);
                response.send(200, { access_token: token });
            } else {
                response.send(401, { message: "User not found" });

            }
        });
});

// define module constructor
module.exports = function(options) {
    // save data shared from parent module
    jwtSecretKey = options.jwtSecretKey;
    jwt = options.jwt;
    User = options.User;
    tokens = options.tokens;
    return router;
};
```

> I also have some 'helper' type methods I would like to use in
>   different 'routing' files.  I do not know how to pass them either.

The usual way to share some common help functions is to put them in their own module and then you just `require()` in that module in any other module that you need to use them.